# xslxwriter library in Python suddenly very slow

Tags: python, pandas, performance, xlsxwriter

I use the xlsxwriter library to format and write pandas dataframes to excel.  The library is necessary because of the various formatting I need (titles, a table, etc., thus I do not use df.to_excel()).  I loop through the rows and columns of a dataframe to write the spreadsheet.

This worked fine for many uses over the past year, including large dataframes (>100k rows, 13 columns).  However, it suddenly became extremely slow.  It still works, but now what used to take a few minutes or so to write (which seems in line with the xlsxwriter documentation at https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_memory.html) now takes forever to write (100 rows takes 40 seconds, so 100k + rows takes forever).  I do not know what is different, as the code itself is the same and does still run, just slowly.  I rebooted my machine, and updated all my libraries including xlsxwriter.  My other code that does not use xlsxwriter all seems to be running at normal speed, so it seems to be specific to xlsxwriter.  I use the Anaconda python distribution.

Is there any reason a single library like xlswriter would all the sudden start running slow?  I am doing this on a work computer so maybe they changed something?  I do know they are planning to update Excel versions but have not done so yet.  I just cannot figure this out.

FYI, my code (which previously ran at a reasonable speed) is below.

Note that if it was possible to write the pandas dataframe to Excel and then format it as a table with formatted title rows, then I would skip the loop, but I don't think this is the case.

```
 # Populate data.
        exceptions = exceptions.fillna('')  # NA values not supported.
        row = 3
        i = 0
        while row < len(exceptions) + 3:
            n = 0
            while n < len(column_formats):
                col_name = column_formats[n][0]
                col_format = column_formats[n][2]
                if col_format == 'string':
                    exceptions[col_name].iloc[i] = str(exceptions[col_name].iloc[i])
                    worksheet.write_string(row, n, exceptions[col_name].iloc[i])
                elif col_format == 'number':
                    if type(exceptions[col_name].iloc[i]) in [int, float, np.int32, np.float32, np.int64, np.float64]:
                        worksheet.write_number(row, n, exceptions[col_name].iloc[i],
                                               number_format)
                    else:
                        worksheet.write_string(row, n, exceptions[col_name].iloc[i])
                elif col_format == 'dollar':
                    if type(exceptions[col_name].iloc[i]) in [int, float, np.int32, np.float32, np.int64, np.float64]:
                        worksheet.write_number(row, n, exceptions[col_name].iloc[i],
                                               dollar_format)
                    else:
                        worksheet.write_string(row, n, exceptions[col_name].iloc[i])
                elif col_format == 'datetime':
                    # If date, then convert to python datetime and write to Excel.
                    if type(exceptions[col_name].iloc[i]) == pd.Timestamp:
                        date = exceptions[col_name].iloc[i].to_pydatetime()
                        worksheet.write_datetime(row, n, date,
                                                 date_format)
                    else:
                        worksheet.write_string(row, n, exceptions[col_name].iloc[i])
                elif col_format == 'boolean':
                    if type(exceptions[col_name].iloc[i]) == bool:
                        worksheet.write_boolean(row, n, exceptions[col_name].iloc[i])
                    else:
                        worksheet.write_string(row, n, exceptions[col_name].iloc[i])
                n +=1
            row += 1
            i += 1
```

Comment: Nothing substantial has changed recently n XlsxWriter that would cause a noticeable change in performance. Just to be sure I ran a performance test with different versions of XlsxWriter going back 3 years and didn't see any significant change. You can test this yourself by installing an older version and re-running your tests. Like this: `pip install xlsxwriter==1.0.0`. Can you try that and let me know.

Comment: I tried with an older version and the updated version and both were the same, and also the problem started even though I hadn't updated so the version was not the reason.  It seems I can do everything I need without a loop.  I originally thought I couldn't format a dataframe the way I wanted with a table, but this proved not to be the case.  I am all set, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am not sure why the loop started taking so long, but I found a way to write this to a pandas dataframe and then add a title, format it, and then make it into a table.  It takes just under a minute for 140k rows and 13 columns.

See https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/pandas_examples.html for details.

Below is how I made the dataframe into a table in case anybody is interested:

```
        if len(column_formats) + ex_cols <= 27:
            col_string = string.ascii_uppercase[len(column_formats) + ex_cols]
        else:
            col_string = 'A' + string.ascii_uppercase[len(column_formats) + ex_cols - 27]

        table_range = ('A3:' + col_string + str(len(exceptions) + 3))
        col_headers = self._create_col_headers(column_formats, override_header)
        worksheet.add_table(table_range, {'style': 'Table Style Medium 4',
                                          'columns': col_headers})

def _create_col_headers(self, column_formats, override_header=None):
        ''''Creates a list of dictionaries of column headers, used to add table
        format in Excel formatting'''
        i = 0
        col_headers = []
        while i < len(column_formats):
            col_name = column_formats[i][0]
            col_headers.append({'header': col_name})
            i += 1

        # Add column for Review Notes (at end) (if no override).
        if override_header is None:
            col_headers.append({'header': 'Review Notes'})

        return col_headers
```